# Create a public ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum

I just want know, If I use this command for create public ethereum node,
please tell me if there are any changes to be done this cmd line
use Azure VM,

> geth --identity "Test.Node" --rpc --rpcport 8080 --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir test.node --port 30303 --nodiscover --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,txpool --networkid 1 console

Answer (score 1):

> --nodiscover

If you use this flag, other peers will be unable to "discover" your node, and so it may not sync successfully, unless you are adding specific peers manually. Is this the intention?

Comment: thanks for your response
I'm planning to create an eth node to do the transaction.

Comment: could you please clarify, whether do I need genesis.json file to create public node or not.